# Kotlin: how to copy file from assets folder to databases folder

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, assets

So the code should be very straight forward just copy the database file to the databases folder. for some reason I keep getting a java.iofilenotfoundexception I'm trying to make this to work in an activity.

my second question is what changes do I need here for it to work in a fragment?

Thanks.

```
// Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
// empty database in the system folder
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun copyDataBase() {

    val outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME

    val myOutput = FileOutputStream(outFileName)
    val myInput = this.assets.open(DATABASE_NAME)

    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var length: Int = myInput.read(buffer)
    while ((length) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
        length = myInput.read(buffer)
    }
    myInput.close()
    myOutput.flush()
    myOutput.close()
}
```

Comment: What is `DATABASE_PATH` and `DATABASE_NAME`?

Comment: By the way Kotlin has a convenient [InputStream.copyTo()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/copy-to.html)  extension (and  [File.copyTo()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/copy-to.html) when the source is also a file)

Comment: I saw those but not really sure how to use them. I tried this File(applicationContext.assets.toString()+DATABASE_NAME).copyTo(File(DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME))